# Assigning to multidimensional arrays javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, multidimensional-array, assign

I have arrays within objects full of false values.

```
var drumOn = {}, bassOn = {}, synthOn = {}, keysOn = {};
var fal = [];    
for(var j=0; j<16; j++){
  fal.push(false);
}

for(var j=0; j<0; j++){
  drumOn['s'+j] = (fal);
  bassOn['s'+j] = (fal);
  synthOn['s'+j] = (fal);
  keysOn['s'+j] = (fal);
}
```

then later I try adding one true value to one array

```
drumOn['s'+ 0][0] = true;
```

This adds a true value to the first element of all the arrays within drumOn and within the other objects too.

The only other thing I'm doing with these objects is checking

```
    if(bassOn['s' + i][j])
```

I was doing this with arrays within arrays and I had the same problem.

This is crazy, I've tried so many things but it makes no sense.

Comment: You are loading the objects all with the *same* array.  They all reference the *same* `fal` array.  So, when you edit one, they all get edited.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copying array by value in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486085/copying-array-by-value-in-javascript)

Comment: `drumOn['s' + j]` will access the __property__ `drumOn.s0`.

Comment: @ryanyuyu: ...which is an array of booleans, yes.

Answer (score 3):

[Copying array by value in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486085/copying-array-by-value-in-javascript)

```
for(var j=0; j<0; j++){
  drumOn['s'+j] = fal.slice();
  bassOn['s'+j] = fal.slice();
  synthOn['s'+j] = fal.slice();
  keysOn['s'+j] = fal.slice();
}
```

`slice` returns a copy of the array.  In your example, all of the items are pointing to the same original array `fal`.  You need to duplicate it.